# Value at index in *unsigned char

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I have a class that holds audio data bytes:

```
class clsAudioData
{
private:
    unsigned char *m_content;
    long m_size;
public:
    clsAudioData();
    ~clsAudioData();
    void Load(string file);
    long Size();
    unsigned char *Content();
    void LoadContent(long size, FILE *f);
};

void  clsAudioData::LoadContent(long size, FILE *f)
{
    m_size =size;
    m_content = new unsigned char[m_size];
    fread(m_content, sizeof(unsigned char), m_size,f);
}
```

I'm trying to printf values at certain positions.
To do that, I tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    printf("audio data = %d\n", nAudioData.Content[i]);
}
```

The compiler tells me:

```
clsAudioData::Content Function doesn't accept 1 argument
```

How could I access an "element" at a certain index to printf it?

Thank you.

Comment: `(nAudioData.Content())[i]` this way?

Comment: @YSC It's an array of bytes.

Comment: `Content` is a member ***function*** that *returns* a pointer to the data (I assume). You need to *call* the function to get a pointer you can index. Perhaps you should consider overloading `operator[]`?

Comment: You should really be using an `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

Comment: either make another `Content(size_t idx)` function that returns an indexed value from `m_content` or call `Content()[idx]` instead of `Content[idx]` directly. `Content` is a function pointer, you can't call it directly with array indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to *call* the `Content` function: `nAudioData.Content()[i]`.

Aside: please make `m_content` a `std::vector<unsigned char>`.  You'll have a lot less chance of leaking memory.